# Redirecting a particular email via dns?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, dns-hosting

Is there any way to setup an MX record or similar so that a particular email address on the domain forwards on to another, rather then doing it at the cpanel or app (outlook, gmail) end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't reroute adresses via dns. dns in mail is only used to determin which smtp server accepts (all) the mail for a specific domain.

you could add a subdomain and have a different MX for addresses of this subdomain.